# REGEX - Remove specified string

Tags: regex, remove-if

I need help with Regex. I have words like `"testBla"`, `"Bla"` and `test"`.
I want to cut the `"test"` from the `"testBla"`. So it should only remove the `"test"` if the given string is larger than 4 characters.
This is what i have:

```
^test\w{4,}
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @MarkByers seeing his answers and questions - probably [tag:JavaScript]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't" work (i.e. it's helpful to provide detail about what your problem is exactly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove `test` if it occurs at the start of the line and is followed by a word character then you could use a non-word-boundary:

```
^test\B
```

See it working online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/UYsuJn4jI8)

If you want to remove `test` if it occurs at the start of the line and is followed by any character (except a new line) then you could use a lookahead:

```
^test(?=.)
```

See it working online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Je1Aw3zUYU)

Comment: The main question is which flavor OP is using. Because the non-word-boundary character catches `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` (aka `[^\w]`) in some Regex flavors so your first example may occasionally not succeed with Javascript Regexp, as an example (consider "testç").

Comment: Thanks! i've choosen the first one. i assume that strings contains only letters(a-z).

Answer (score 1):

This one will only capture the 'test' part in a word: `\btest(?=\w{4,})`. I'm assuming you're using a regex engine that has zero length lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using JavaScript, try this:

```
string.replace(/test([^]+)/i, "$1");

       'Bla'.replace(/test([^]+)/i, "$1"); // 'Bla'
      'test'.replace(/test([^]+)/i, "$1"); // 'test'
   'testBla'.replace(/test([^]+)/i, "$1"); // 'Bla'
   'blaTest'.replace(/test([^]+)/i, "$1"); // 'blaTest'
'blaTestbla'.replace(/test([^]+)/i, "$1"); // 'blaTestbla'
```

This will remove `test` from the string, only if the string starts with `test`, and only if there's more in the string than only `test`. I added `i` to make the regex case-insensitive.

Comment: `/test(.)/` would also work, no?  Also, you probably want the leading `^` to mirror the OP's question.

Comment: @broofa: `/test(.+)/` should work, but that will break at newline characters. the `^` is not required in my regex. (See my examples)